# Invariant violation: ViewPagerAndroid has been removed from React Native - ERROR ON IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-viewpager

[image]

Hi guys! This is an error I struggle with for the past 2 days. It happens when trying to run the react native project on ios. My package.json doesn't even have @react-native-community/viewpager dependency and I don't use it in my project, yet after 'npm install' , there are viewpager dependencies in my package-lock.json and in node_modules too.

[image]
[image]

Do I need viewpager to run this project? If yes, how can I make it work and if not, how do I eliminate it completly?

Comment: were you able to find the error?

Comment: same here, have anyone resolved the issue?